# Windows Docker2boot example cannot open page from localhost

Tags: flask, virtualbox, docker

I installed Docker2boot on my windows computer and I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/) , trying to set up a containing running as a flask server so I can access the page outside the container/locally.

I kickstarted the flask server and I am assuming it is running by calling `docker top` command.

[image]

However, I tried to open it in my chrome browser and cannot open it. It doesn't tell me the page doesn't exist but instead, just hangs there forever.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

---

UPDATE, it works on the Ubuntu Virutal Box on my windows machine in the end.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the docker is running within a VM.  You need to find out the IP address of the VM & use that IP address + port to access.

To get the IP address, run...

`boot2docker ssh ip addr show dev eth1`

... which will give you something like this...

```
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:0e:46:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.59.103 brd 192.168.59.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe0e:46b7/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(It would not let me post with the actual IP address included)

Then use this IP address to connect (in this example... `http://192.168.59.103:49153`)

Don't forget to use the correct post from the `docker ps` output.